# How to create xpath for checkout created of div and class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For below element I am not able to create xpath as it contains only div and class. Also How to create dynamic xpaths for this kind of scenarios.

[image]

Html is

```
<div class="MuiGrid-root campaign-usecase-item MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12">
 <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-5" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss739 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary payment-check-box MuiIconButton-colorSecondary" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
        <input class="jss742" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value=""> 
        <span class="material-icons MuiIcon-root jss732" aria-hidden="true">
        <img class="jss731" src="/static/media/unchecked.70d37fef.svg"></span> 
      </span>
     <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
   </span><h3>STANDARD</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-6">2FA</div>
 <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-1">$ 60.-</div>
</div>
```

Issue is, its should be dynamic so as per the values such as 2Fa, Bridge etc can be selected as checkbox.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automate the webpage, the way it is designed. I would suggest you the css locator startegy here.

As per the above html snippet it looks like the grid, displays the items as a grid rows.

Firstly identify the total grid rows i.e

```
[class*="MuiGrid-root campaign-usecase-item"], the above locator describe the each grid cell
```

Once you able to identify all grid rows moves to identify required row index

```
locator : [class*="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item"]:not([style]) will give you the 
name (like 2fa) and price of each section
```

checkbox locator: input[type='checkbox']

```
List<WebElement> gridRows = driver.findElements(By.cssLocator("[class*='MuiGrid- 
root campaign-usecase-item']"));
int totalGridCells = gridRows.size;
int reuiredGridRowIndex;
for(int i=0' i<totalGridCells; : i++){
    if(gridRows.get(i).findElements(By.cssLocator("[class*='MuiGrid-root MuiGrid- 
    item']:not([style])").get(0).getText().equals("2FA")){
    // 2fa value will be dynamic and pass as function argument
    reuiredGridRowIndex = i;
    break;
     }
}
```

// now base upon index you can click or get price of any cell value of the disered row

// click on checkbox

```
driver.findElements(By.cssLocator("[class*='MuiGrid-root campaign-usecase- 
    item']")).get(reuiredGridRowIndex 
      ).findElement(By.cssLocator("input[type='checkbox']")).click()
```

// get price

```
driver.findElements(By.cssLocator("[class*='MuiGrid-root campaign-usecase- 
    item']")).get(reuiredGridRowIndex ).findElements(By.cssLocator(" 
        [class*="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item"]:not([style])")).get(1).getText()
```

yes, there are more line of code but the above code is more flexible, scalable and stable as compare to xpath strategy. You may need to change locator value as i do not have the complete page html.

Comment: Man you are genius. It works. Also can you tell me how to create css selector like you, because your method is amazing. i want to learn css selector, so I can be good in finding xpaths or css selectors. Please guide and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is not having xpath any more for even unit testing. adding data-test="answer-1" or better semantic value for data-test can help you even on maintaining your test better. other locators tend to break your tests more often

Comment: then how to perform automation test?

Comment: both selenium and cypress support this data-test. you can update your selectors to use data-test attribute and you are more safe with it. of course you have to make the data-test automatically but this time it's not tied to html structure anymore

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Java by head, but here some psuedo code:

```
var found = false;
var search = "2FA";
var usecases = driver.findElements(By.Class("campaign-usecase-item"); // returns 6 divs
foreach(var case in usecases) { // loop all divs
  var label = case.findElement(By.Class("MuiGrid-grid-xs-6")); // find labels
  if (label.text == search ) { // if label found
    found = true;
    case.findElement(By.TagName("input")).click(); // find first input within case div and click
    break; //breaks for out of foreach loop
  }
}
if(!found) throw exception("label {search} not found");
```

Key learning is here that you can search within found elements. I use this a lot. It makes possible complex xpaths very readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string sectionName = "2FA";   
driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//div[contains(@class, 'campaign-usecase-item')]/div[contains(@text, '%s')]/preceding-sibling::div/span[contains(@class, 'MuiCheckbox-root')]//input", sectionName)));
```

And you can set the name of the desired section

Comment: I really liked the way you are finding xpath. can you tell me from where I can learn more about it. I took your xpath container and used in below answer and it worked. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can see more details about XPath here: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html, also there are many examples